# Get single IP address without pipe

Tags: bash, ip, hostname, ifconfig

`Centos7` using `bash`. I need to set an environmental variable, `$IP`. However, the command to set the variable is done through a company system that expects `|` to be the delimiter between variables (i.e., I'd pass the system a list in the form `myIP=something|myOtherIP=something_else|envVar3=17`).

I am planning for a use case where the IP address is always internal (10.x.x.x). Is there any command that can return just the one IP address I care about, without using pipe?

`hostname -i` returns the wrong address (doesn't start with 10.). `hostname -I` includes the correct address, but it's second in the list of seven. I can easily get the IP with either `hostname -I` or `ifconfig`, but it involves piping to grep and then using regex to find the one that starts with 10. I doubt there's any easy way (honestly, I doubt it's possible), but I figured I'd ask anyway.

Comment: Can you not get your IP variable in one step that uses pipes, then pass in that list in a separate step, or do you need to pass `something` as a command that will end up printing the IP you want?

Comment: Is it always the 2nd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
grep -o  "10[^ ]*"<<<`hostname -I`
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer from [abhishek phukan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8577085/abhishek-phukan), if you always want the second IP in the list - you could use:

```
cut -f2 -d' ' <<< `hostname -I`
```

Thanks for the great answer abhishek!

Comment: :) . Yep this is a good solution too if the Ip is always on the 2nd position. And awk would be better though I guess , this might fail if the spaces are not uniform